# Emulator has no internet connection

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I know there are other topics on this but none of these actually worked for me so i am going to ask it again.

- my Androidmanifest.xml does have permission from internet.
- I allowed network sharing
- Airplane mode is off

it just doesn't seem to work and is pretty frustrating. would like to have some help on this been trying to fix it for 8 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install emulator system again. The system image may contain bugs that why emulator has no internet connection.